# pass stopped searching linked directories

Tags: password, password-store

I use [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) (standard unix password manager) and it stopped searching linked directories, eg:

```
> pass find test
Search Terms: test
├── mine -> /mnt/params/.password-store/mine  [recursive, not followed]
(...)

> ls -l /home/kossak/.password-store/mine         10:44:32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kossak kossak 32 2017-01-19  /home/kossak/.password-store/mine -> /mnt/params/.password-store/mine

> ls -ld /mnt/params/.password-store/mine
drwx------ 2 kossak kossak 4096 2021-05-06  /mnt/params/.password-store/mine
```

Folder `mine` is not recursive, it is a link to different folder. It was working some time ago, but now it stopped.

Any ideas how to fix it?

I'm using:

- pass v1.7.4
- Linux Manjaro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pass` [apparently uses `tree`](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/src/password-store.sh#n417) for the `pass find` command.

Running the underlying `tree` command¹ gives the same issue, for me:

```
$ tree -N -C -l --noreport -P '*test*' --prune --matchdirs --ignore-case /home/user/.password-store
/home/user/.password-store
└── symlink -> /path/to/another/dir  [recursive, not followed]
```

You can also see the "recursive, not followed" error [in the `tree` source code](https://github.com/nodakai/tree-command/blob/master/tree.c#L924).

[An answer about the manifestation of this behaviour in `tree`](https://superuser.com/questions/1313755/why-tree-command-mark-symlink-as-recursive) says "If the inode number of the directory pointed to by the symlink is found in the hash table (the one that is populated with saveino and findino), it will simply skip it."

I haven't been able to find a solution yet, but my guess is that something strange is going on with the code in `tree` which saves and looks up inode numbers.

Like you, I also remember that symlinks like this used to work in `pass`, I don't remember exactly when they stopped working. The last [meaningful change to anything `tree`-related in `pass`](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/commit/?id=6cbdb2d) was in 2014, maybe this is a regression in `tree`, then?

---

¹To find the `tree` command, I added `set -x` above the linked `tree -N -C` line in `password-store.sh`

Comment: This has been fixed in `tree` 2.1.1. I can confirm `pass` can now search symlinked directories

Changelog statement: "Fix issue where tree would never descend (-l) a symbolic link when a full tree is gathered (--du/matchdirs/prune) (gitlab @6ramr)"

Comment: Awesome. thanks! Will give it a go when the new `tree` is available on my platform :)

Comment: @brent it works! Thank you :)